# How to hook up on Navigation Property Change when using DBContext and POCOs

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using a Database First codestrategy, and have POCOs and context generated by `EF4.x DBContext Generator`.

In short when I was using ObjectContext, for triggering a notification I was extending a entity like this:

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {

        this.AddressReference.AssociationChanged += AddressReference_AssociationChanged;            
    }

    private void AddressReference_AssociationChanged(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("Address");
    }

}
```

Is there something similar when working with DBContext and POCOs ?

**EDIT:**

I need this for an ChangeNotification when Customer.Address = new Address. By default scalar properties are raising ChangeNotifications but Navigation Properties are not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged when using EF Code-First?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991396/do-i-need-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-when-using-ef-code-first)

Comment: Well, possible. But to be specific I'm full aware of the EF dynamic proxies that extend basic POCO's at runtime and implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and that 
[msdn bugreport](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532257/entity-framework-navigation-properties-don-t-raise-the-propertychanged-event) the proxies don't work very very well. So basically this is another question, but it`s kinda related just because I`m implementing this in an MVVM-WPF solution.