# Adding a record to EF 4.1 does not reflect in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a data bound list box that was built using the EF 4.1 model first.  So all my classes where built for me.  Because I have three controls that reflect the table data that traces back from the foreign key.  this.lstBox2.ItemSource = entityContext.TableObject2.ToList() will return every record.  Not the records that the M-D are showing limited by the foreign key constraint.

```
TableObject2 class2 = new TableObject2();
class2.value1 = 0;
class2.value2 = "new location";

using (TKOEntities entityContext = new TKOEntities())
{
                entityContext.TableObject2.AddObject(class2);
                entityContext.SaveChanges();
                this.lstBox2.ItemsSource = null;
}
```

SaveChanges does update the data into the database.   But the control is not refreshed (this.lstBox2.Refresh() doesn't work).  If I try to set the value to the control.  I also get the us ItemControl.ItemSource error.  How do I assign the control the updated values saved to the entitycontext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
this.lstBox2.ItemsSource = null;
```

Try fetching the data from entityContext after you save the changes to rebuild your list:

```
this.lstBox2.ItemsSource = entityContext.TableObject2.ToList();
```

There is a better approach you could take I'm sure, but to quickly get your databack out of the db and into the list, this should work.

Also a quick code bit, you can use object initializer:

```
TableObject2 class2 = new TableObject2 { value1 = 0, value2 = "new location" };
```

Comment: this.lstBox2.ItemsSource = entityContext.TableObject2.ToList(); Will return everything back and does reload the data in the control but it is everything  and not limited to what is selected on the first control by Master-Detail.

Comment: Then you'll need to apply a select filter prior to doing the ToList() and pass in what the first control has as its selected value.

Comment: or, use the Include method and pass in TableObject2 as its selector to get the related TableObject2 objects by fk.    var obj = entityContext.MDTable.Include("TableObject2").FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = slected.Id); this.lstBox2.ItemsSource = obj.TableObject2s.ToList();

Answer (score 1):

The model changes are not automatically propagated to the view-model or your view (as I can see you don't have a MVVM view-model?)

You'd normally need to `Bind` and do `PropertyChanged`.

This is writing from a device and very rough and fast (I may have mistyped something etc.)...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding YourCollectionProperty} >
```

in your 'view-model' (or if that's your 'control', which I don't recommend, then do something like `{Binding ElementName=_mywin, Path=YourCollectionProperty}`) define the property as...

```
public ObservableCollection<POCOItem> YourCollectionProperty 
{
get
{
     return _collection ?? (_collection = WrapModel());
}
set
{}}
```

Implement `IPropertyChanged interface`
When your model is updated...

```
_collection = null;
OnPropertyChanged("YourCollectionProperty");
```

`ObservableCollection` is useless here (an array/list will do just the same - keeping model collection in sync isn't easy.

So, if you need to be closely tied to your model - you could make your model navigation property `ICollection` to be `ObservableCollection` (though there're pros and cons but not to get into that).

e.g. see this one [Do I need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged when using EF Code-First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991396/do-i-need-to-implement-inotifypropertychanged-when-using-ef-code-first)

In that case - when just adding new items - that should go automatically to you ListBox.

If you refresh the collection - then do the above (set PropertyChanged for the collection property)

`Item Properties are not automatically updated` - unless you implement IPropertyChanged on your model as well.