# MVVM Model to ViewModel communication

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm

I have a simple scenario with a View, a ViewModel and a custom type class.

The model class is something like:

```
public class Person : Validation.DataError, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyProperty

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion


    public global::System.String name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _name;
```

}

In the ViewModel I have a Person property:

```
private Model.Person person;

        public Model.Person Person
        {
            get
            {
                return person;
            }
            set 
            {
                this.person= value;

                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Person");
                this.SavePersonCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
```

In my View I have a textbox that is bound to Person.name

So the ViewModel is not executing the **set method** because the Person object is still the same... it is executing the set method in the **Model property**.

I want to let the user change the person name and make a call to another method (search through a web service and other stuff...) and I think this functionality should be in the ViewModel.

I'm using Messenger from MVVM Light toolkit to communicate between different viewmodels and between views and viewmodels.

Now I don't know if I should use a mediator too for this or if I should know another way to solve this.

Comment: Looks like you're going down a good path.  I see you're implementing validation / INotifyPropertyChanged and stuff.  Maybe you want to check out Csla.Net, which will handle this stuff for you.  It provides a framework on which to build great models, as well as offers some help for the various UIs it supports (basically all of them).  http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of the Person in your ViewModel and check for the "Name" property, or whatever you wanna do:

```
Person.PropertyChanged += new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler(Person_PropertyChanged);

void Person_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "Name")
    {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: That was so simple!! Thanks for your help :-D

Comment: I was looking into this same issue and thought I had to go through giving the ViewModel dependency properties to so I could bind element in the View to the ViewModel property and then the ViewModel property to the View property. That was turning into a hairy mess and still wasn't working. Your answer is a very simple way to propagate model changes out to the GUI without a bunch of hassle. Thanks for this straight-forward answer!