# MVVM With Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have been downloading a lot of example code to help me gain a better understanding of MVVM within silverlight.

One of the things I have noticed is an inconsistency within the sample code I have downloaded. Some for example implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the viewmodels, where others implement it on the Model.

Which is the preferred way of handling property changes, should it be handled at the model level or the viewmodel level?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MVVM should the ViewModel or Model implement INotifyPropertyChanged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772214/in-mvvm-should-the-viewmodel-or-model-implement-inotifypropertychanged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling (Notifying) property changes in the viewmodel would seem more natural if this is to update the item that's being displayed in the view by databinding.

One of the reasons for having a viewmodel in the first place is that it holds the data from the model in such a way that it's easy for the view to bind to it.
So, if the main reason for your INotifyPropertyChange in is to update the item which is bound in the view, you should update it in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use `DependencyProperty` instead of `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but the idea is the same.

Their purpose is to notify the view controls, they are bound to, that they have changed so the view can update. This implies a weak connection between the view and whatever holds the property or object. In MVVM, the view should never have any link to the model because of separation of concerns.

I will often have physically force this by creating a separate project for each of the view, viewmodel, and model. So, the answer to your question is that the `INotifyPropertyChanged` should be implemented at the viewmodel level because the view should never touch anything from the model level. Having said this, MVVM is just a coding paradigm to make the programmers job easier, so there could be reasons to implement it differently if it means making your job easier and it doesn't having any negative consequences.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bryan, I wish I could mark two answers as correct but as Esther answered first I have marked this as the correct answer and have up voted yours.