# In MVVM Pattern INotifyPropertyChanged can use only in ViewModel or we can use in Model or Bothes?

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

I read lots of articles, And found that lots of people use INotifyPropertyChanged in ViewModel either Model as well. So, I am confused about INotifyPropertyChanged where to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MVVM should the ViewModel or Model implement INotifyPropertyChanged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772214/in-mvvm-should-the-viewmodel-or-model-implement-inotifypropertychanged)

Answer (score 0):

A popular approach is to use a base class which Implements InotifyPropertyChanged interface and then inherit this base class in your View Model.

example:

```
    public class NotifyPropertyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then inherit the base class in the view model:

```
class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyBase
```

Finally, raise the OnPropertyChanged event in the property setter of your view model passing in the property name string as the parameter:

```
  private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
```

Now your UI should update at run time provided the binding is declared correctly in the Xaml.